# js why else{} being executed?

Tags: javascript, loops

Need little help from you. Got this code, but not sure why my else statement being executed, even though "if" meets the requirements. Can someone explain me that ?
And as well, can someone point me to the right direction.. every time I enter a letter, regardless it is correct or not, it is being printed to guessed-letter list, and i'm not sure how can I stop printing it 8 times? 
I have saved my code to fiddle as well, if that is little easier: http://jsfiddle.net/5NfYj/

```
function guess(){
        output = '';
        userLetter = document.forms[0].letter.value;
        document.forms[0].letter.value = '';

        for(var c=0;c<theWord.length;c++){
            if(userLetter === letters[c]){
                display[c] = userLetter;
                win--;
            }else { 
                wrongGuess.push(userLetter);
                document.forms[0].guessedLetters.value = wrongGuess; 
                }

            output = output + display[c] + ' ';
        }

        document.forms[0].result.value = output;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/5NfYj/3/

```
        for(var c=0;c<theWord.length;c++){
            if(userLetter === letters[c]){
                display[c] = userLetter;
                win--;
            }

            output = output + display[c] + ' ';
        }
        wrongGuess.push(userLetter);
        document.forms[0].guessedLetters.value = wrongGuess;
```

For example, when I enter a, your code iterates over all 8 characters of apetiser. It matches the first character and displays it in box, but for all other it picks the else branch, hence display a in guess box 7 times.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript string comparision is case sensitive. I can get it to work if I put a lowercase character inside the input, but it won't enter if I put a uppercase character since your for loop is comparing it to lowercase characters only. You can use the [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method to convert the input value so it will work even if the user puts a uppercase letter.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5NfYj/1/

Note: as @daniel0mullins pointed out, your logic to add the wrong guesses will run 8 times because it is inside the `for` loop. You should use a flag that denotes if it is wrong and only add it to your list once you finish the loop. Check his answer to learn more about how to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

It's displaying multiple guesses because you are looping through the entire word. Try this instead:

```
function guess(){
        output = document.forms[0].result.value;
        userLetter = document.forms[0].letter.value;
        document.forms[0].letter.value = '';
        var guessInWord = false;

        for(var c=0;c<theWord.length;c++){
            if(userLetter === letters[c]){
                display[c] = userLetter;
                var newOutput = output.split('');
                newOutput[c] = userLetter;
                output = newOutput.join('');
                guessInWord = true;
                win--;
            }                   
        }

        if(!guessInWord) {
           wrongGuess.push(userLetter);
           document.forms[0].guessedLetters.value = wrongGuess;
        }

        document.forms[0].result.value = output;    
    }
```

That way it will only push to the wrongGuess array AFTER checking the entire word, instead of after each letter.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmX7T/2/)